# Dynamic Image Slider Android

Tags: java, android

I am using the [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library in my app for an image slider.  I am loading images using a `Hashmap` like this:

```
HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
url_maps.put("Image 1", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");
url_maps.put("Image 2", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");
url_maps.put("Image 3", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");


for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
    // initialize a SliderLayout
    textSliderView
            .description(name)
            .image(url_maps.get(name))
            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

    //add your extra information
    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
    textSliderView.getBundle()
            .putString("extra",name);

    mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
}
```

Note: I am setting the key of the `HashMap` as the description for each image.

How do I make this slider dynamic?

I want to load the images dynamically from a json feed which looks like this:

```
{
  "Images": [
    {
      "title": "title",
      "Image": "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Distribution",
      "Image": "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Distribution",
      "Image": "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I do it using a `HashMap` or do I need to use an alternative? If yes please suggest.  Or do I use a different library? If yes please give reference. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type= new TypeToken<List<ImageData>>(){}.getType();
List<ImageData> imageDataList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

where `jsonString` is the string representing your JSON array

the `ImageData` class would look like this

```
public class ImageData {
    String title;
    String Image;
    public ImageData(){};
}
```

then iterate over the list as follows

```
for(ImageData data : imageDataList){
    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
    // initialize a SliderLayout
    textSliderView
            .description(data.title)
            .image(data.Image)
            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

    //add your extra information
    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
    textSliderView.getBundle()
            .putString("extra",data.title);

    mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class as a Structure of your Data

```
class ImageUrls{
   String imageTitle,imageUrl;
   ImageUrls(String imageTitle, String imageUrl){
      this.imageTitle = imageTitle;
      this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
   }
}
```

Now make a `ArrayList<ImageUrls> url_maps`

Add data in the ArrayList

```
    url_maps.add("Image 1", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");
    url_maps.add("Image 2", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");
    url_maps.add("Image 3", "http://example.com/./project_image/example.jpg");
```

and add this data to your ImageSlider

```
 For(int count : ArrayList.size()){
     //here you can get your data from arraylist using 
     arraylist.get(postion).imageTitle 
     arraylist.get(postion).imageUrl 

  }
```

Comment: Can't i do this using a hash map ??

Comment: This approach worked for me when making a ImageSlider, I think it could be possible with hash maps too but never tried it.